# Ajax link is not working even I try my best on HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've created a form with the parameter `id='subscribe'`

For some reason, my ajax is not working and redirects to `example.com/null`. I also noticed that if we use ajax then the window never loads and redirect and all processes works silently. But it doesn't seem to be working. My code is below; please tell me where my mistake might be.

Your regards,
New user

**MY HTML**

```
<form name="subscribe" id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" value="" name="subscribe_email" id="subscribe_email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="subscribe_name" id="subscribe_name" />
    <a class="btn" onclick="email_subscribe()">Subscribe</a>

</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function email_subscribe(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './folder1/page2.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:$("#subscribe").serialize(),
        success: function (html) {
            try {
                eval(html);
            } 
            catch (e) {
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of clicking on a link, which is to open the page that the link points to (if there's no `href` attribute, it defaults to the current page.

You can use `href="#"` to make it stay on the current page.

```
<a class="btn" href="#" onclick="email_subscribe()">Subscribe</a>
```

or you can return `false` from the `onclick` code.

```
<a class="btn" onclick="email_subscribe(); return false">Subscribe</a>
```

BTW, `eval(html)` seems very strange. The argument to `eval()` must be Javascript code, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your link navigate you to another page. Use `<a href="#" ...>`, or use the following code:

```
function email_subscribe(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

And call this function like: `<a onclick="email_subscribe(event)" ...>`.

```js
function email_subscribe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './folder1/page2.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:$("#subscribe").serialize(),
        success: function (html) {
            try {
                eval(html);
            } 
            catch (e) {
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="subscribe" id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" value="" name="subscribe_email" id="subscribe_email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="subscribe_name" id="subscribe_name" />
    <a class="btn" onclick="email_subscribe(event)">Subscribe</a>
</form>
```

Comment: You also need to pass `event` when calling the function.

Comment: Where do you pass it? It needs to be `onclick="email_subscribe(event)"`

Comment: Yes, I think you're talking about the function definition. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @חיים פרידמן could you pls complete your code. I am not understand